# aws-sdk-go dynamodbattribute unmarshal list of maps not unmarshalling

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I have a Dynamodb Table that has the following struct:

```
type StatusItem struct {
    requestStatus string
    timestamp string
    RequestId string
}
```

I have the code as such:

```
items := []StatusItem{}
err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, &items)
if err != nil {
    exitWithError(fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal Query result items, %v", err))
}

// Print out the items returned
for i, item := range items {
    fmt.Println(i)
    fmt.Printf(item.RequestId, item.requestStatus)
}
```

However, `items` is empty.

when i put a watcher in items, i can see the it unmarshals to the struct, but all the values are empty.

if i do:
 `log.println(result.items)` i can see the values there (though a bit ugly)

```
%!(EXTRA string=)[map[timestamp:{
  S: "2018-04-18 12:04:43.761"
} RequestId:{
  S: "9"
} requestStatus:{
  S: "REQUEST_RECEIVED"
}]
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The fields are not exported, so the dynamodb package can't write them.

Comment: @Peter how do you `export` the fields?

Comment: Change the name so they start with upper case characters.

Comment: This is great. Go 1.10 however is suggesting `var items []StatusItem` instead of `items := []StatusItem{}`. 10/10 solution though thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter for pointing me in the right direction.

The solution is simple (though rather dumb that that was the case).

as noted in : https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/3512417fb0-private-vs-public-struct-members

lowercase starting members are private, and Capital was public.

in order to get it working correctly, i needed to update my struct from:

```
type StatusItem struct {
    requestStatus string
    timestamp string
    RequestId string
}
```

to:

```
type StatusItem struct {
    RequestStatus string
    Timestamp string
    RequestId string
}
```